# Server comes to a standstill when using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, tcp, wamp

I have a basic scraper which visits a URL, checks for a link to another given URL, and returns the anchor text for any found links. The scraper also returns the http status both the source and target page for each link.

The scraper is being run from a dedicated Windows 7 machine running WAMP. 8 gigs of RAM (Memory is not an issue in this as the scraper doesn't even use 30% of what's available with the .ini file set to use as much as it wants). As it's being run on behalf of a business, the internet connection is a fixed IP fibre optics line running around 50mb transfer speed).

The curl wrapper I am using is https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class, and this is being executed via WAMP (Apache 2.4.4, PHP 5.4.16) stack on a pretty powerful machine.

The cURL version I am using is:

```
'version_number' => int 466432
'age' => int 3
'features' => int 3005
'ssl_version_number' => int 0
'version' => string '7.30.0' (length=6)
'host' => string 'i386-pc-win32' (length=13)
'ssl_version' => string 'OpenSSL/0.9.8y' (length=14)
'libz_version' => string '1.2.7' (length=5)
```

The scraper chunks the URLs into groups of 175, and then runs them through cURL multi - outputting the results to a CSV.

My issue is that wwhen the scraper runs the first time (processing 1000 URLs or so in around 10 minutes), accessing the server becomes a little slow. But when run for a second time, the server becomes unresponsive and no internet activity can take place via that machine.

What is confusing me is that when I watch Resource Monitor, the number of active TCP connections moves between 300/500 for the first run, and then will not move past 10 active connections after that point.

What is really strange, is that resource monitor is showing that only 10 TCP connections are active/available (shown via the sparkline graph), but the TCP connections info tab shows a few hundred connections being run by httpd.exe - all under the same PID but with different ports.

**Why does the amount of active TCP connections being used reduce so drastically, while the Apache httpd.exe process is still holding onto the ports?**

**What defines how many active TCP connections a windows PC can have, and what about cURL requests would be effectively reducing this number?**

Here is a copy of the function running the cURL calls:

```
private function getUrls_curl ($urls = array(), $statusOnly = FALSE)
{
    $curl = new \DAMC\modules\_global\curl();

    //set some extra options
    $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
    $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '300');
    $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    if ($statusOnly === FALSE)
    {
        $curl->success( array($this, 'parseUrl') );
        $curl->error( array($this, 'error') );
    }
    else
    {
        $curl->complete( array($this, 'statusOnly') );
        $curl->error( array($this, 'statusOnly') );
    }

    $curl->get($urls);
    $curl->close();
}
```

The `$curl->get()` method is defined in the library I linked above, and executes the curl_multi as follows:

```
public function get($url_mixed, $data=array()) 
{
    if (is_array($url_mixed)) 
    {
        $curl_multi = curl_multi_init();
        $this->_multi_parent = true;

        $this->curls = array();

        foreach ($url_mixed as $url) 
        {
            $curl = new Curl();
            $curl->_multi_child = true;
            $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_URL, $this->_buildURL($url, $data), $curl->curl);
            $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
            $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
            $this->_call($this->_before_send, $curl);
            $this->curls[] = $curl;

            $curlm_error_code = curl_multi_add_handle($curl_multi, $curl->curl);
            if (!($curlm_error_code === CURLM_OK)) {
                throw new \ErrorException('cURL multi add handle error: ' .
                    curl_multi_strerror($curlm_error_code));
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->curls as $ch) 
        {
            foreach ($this->_options as $key => $value) 
            {
                $ch->setOpt($key, $value);
            }
        }

        do {
            $status = curl_multi_exec($curl_multi, $active);
        } while ($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);

        foreach ($this->curls as $ch)
            $this->exec($ch);

    }
    else 
    {
        $this->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $this->_buildURL($url_mixed, $data));
        $this->setOpt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        $this->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        return $this->exec();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include additional details which may be relevant, such as OS, Apache, PHP, and cURL versions. Not sure if it'll make a difference, but you could try running directly through the CLI instead of Apache.

Comment: There is no code there relating to `curl_multi_` in that sample code either?

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley Info added.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I included the method which actually performs the cURL GET request.

Comment: More info needed. What exactly is your hardware. i386 win32 tells us very little about the hardware. What Windows version? XP? Win 7? Win 8?  Win 2008 server? How much internal memory? How fast is your Internet connection? Are you running on a dedicated Windows box at a hosting facility? Or at home? If you are scraping from your box at home, don't. Do it on a dedicated Windows server. Last thing you want is your ISP closing your account.

Comment: @WonTonSoup I have added what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the timeout of your curl-Request (300sec) vs. the timeout of the PHPScript (http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php)

If your script stops before the cURL-Timeout you will never get a response.